# IOS - How to send all DNS traffic to go through the VPN configured internal DNS server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, dns

When VPN connection is established,
DNS servers configured by ISP will be in 1st resolver list (list contains Domains and name servers).

DNS servers configured by VPN connection will be in 2nd resolver list.
If i configured xyz.com as domain suffix  then DNS request for any abc.xyz.com gets resolved.But when user tries to access other internal sites like pqr.com (not configured domain) doesn’t get resolved.

Is there any right APIs to update the DNS server list (without root priviledge) and also sending all DNS traffic to the VPN configured DNS Server?

Comment: Did you try "Send all traffic" when you connect via VPN?

Comment: Yes @mikep, i am sending all the traffic under VPN connection.